# Can I tell CMake a specific target and its dependencies shouldn't be built in parallel?

Tags: cmake

I have a submodule (added with `add_subdirectory`) with a target which should be built with `-j1`. Can I change `CMakeLists.txt` to make sure it's always built this way? My current workaround is to build this target separately before building targets which use it.

Comment: Why on earth do you need to do this? If a target can't be built with multithreading that's a big problem. Is this C++/C code or a custom dependency?

Comment: You are creating "XY" problem; instead of asking for help on how to implement your solution, describe the problem you are trying to solve.  ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0):

*IF you are **only** using Ninja*, you can use [the `JOB_POOL` mechanism](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/JOB_POOLS.html):

> Ninja only: List of available pools.
>
> A pool is a named integer property and defines the maximum number of concurrent jobs which can be started by a rule assigned to the pool. The [`JOB_POOLS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_gbl/JOB_POOLS.html) property is a semicolon-separated list of pairs using the syntax NAME=integer (without a space after the equality sign).
>
> For instance:
>
> ```
> set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY JOB_POOLS two_jobs=2 ten_jobs=10)
> ```
>
> Defined pools could be used globally by setting [`CMAKE_JOB_POOL_COMPILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_JOB_POOL_COMPILE.html#variable:CMAKE_JOB_POOL_COMPILE) and [`CMAKE_JOB_POOL_LINK`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_JOB_POOL_LINK.html#variable:CMAKE_JOB_POOL_LINK) or per target by setting the target properties [`JOB_POOL_COMPILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/JOB_POOL_COMPILE.html#prop_tgt:JOB_POOL_COMPILE) and [`JOB_POOL_LINK`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/JOB_POOL_LINK.html#prop_tgt:JOB_POOL_LINK). Custom commands and custom targets can specify pools using the option `JOB_POOL`. Using a pool that is not defined by `JOB_POOLS` causes an error by ninja at build time.
>
> If not set, this property uses the value of the [`CMAKE_JOB_POOLS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_JOB_POOLS.html#variable:CMAKE_JOB_POOLS) variable.
>
> Build targets provided by CMake that are meant for individual interactive use, such as install, are placed in the console pool automatically.

You will need to do something like:

```
set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY JOB_POOLS "no_parallel=1")
set_property(TARGET your_target_name PROPERTY JOB_POOL_COMPILE "no_parallel")
get_property(target_deps TARGET your_target_name PROPERTY LINK_LIBRARIES)
set_target_propertes(${target_deps} PROPERTIES JOB_POOL "no_parallel")
unset(target_deps)
```

About the part on setting it for dependencies- I'm not sure if it will work if any of the dependencies are inside generator expressions. If it doesn't, you can raise a discussion with the CMake dev team.

Disclaimer: I've never actually tried this and I don't know if it works.